# Interesting editing style

Tags: photo-editing, photographer

Came across this wedding photog and was interested in his style of editing. anybody knows how to achieve this style of edits in Lightroom? it seems like it's of low contrast, muted colours and low highlights. A little yellow tint throughout the whole picture too?
http://thomastan.sg/2017/10/joanne-aric-empress-asian-civilisation-museum/

Comment: Welcome to Photography at Stack Exchange! Please read our guide for asking this type of question here and edit the question header to include a verbal description of the qualities of the linked photos you are interested in. [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871)

Comment: As it's been 8 months and stooopeh hasn't come back to clarify, vtc as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a fairly flat contrast curve, fairly warm color balance, and a bit of post including smooth gradient vignette (seemingly darkening the upper half of images more?) and some burning and dodging.

The overall impression I have is "flat" and "warm".